# How to subtract 2 string columns in a Pyspark dataframe

Tags: string, dataframe, pyspark, subtraction

Below is the scenario:
Consider a Pyspark dataframe having 2 columns like below:

{
fullname: facebook,
lastname: book
}

I want a new column firstname by subracting fullname and lastname like below

{
firstname:face,
lastname:book
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('facebook','book')
  ], ['fullname','lastname'])

df.withColumn('firstname', F.expr("regexp_replace(fullname,lastname,'')")).show()
```

```
+--------+--------+---------+
|fullname|lastname|firstname|
+--------+--------+---------+
|facebook|    book|     face|
+--------+--------+---------+
```